# Get logs for repo remotely

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to get logs for a mercurial repo like so:

```
hg log -v "http://some/remote/repository"
```

instead of

```
hg log -v "C:\Users\Repo"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercurial does not support that operation. You firstly have to clone the repository.

See more [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.How_can_I_do_a_.22hg_log.22_of_a_remote_repository.3F)

Comment: Ok thanks for this. Would there be any possible way to get any info about a repo remotely using cmd prompts or scripts in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an http-served mercurial repository (which you seem to) you can get the log by going to `http://some/remote/repository` in your web browser.  You can also start a web server on any repo by issuing the `hg serve` command.  By default, this will start a web server on port 8000 and you can view it by going to `http://repothost:8000/` or, if local, `http://localhost:8000/`.